# Checkbox array show item checked in list

Tags: angular, checkbox, checkboxlist

I have list of all company roles that can be added to user, and also I have list that I get from user for roles that he currently have. Both i get from service. I want to compare these two lists and roles that exist make checked when I show them in html list.

My html:

```
<div class="roles-div">
<div style="text-align: center;">
    <label class="label-roles">Select User Roles</label>
</div>
<form #rolesForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="submitRole(rolesForm)" >
<div class="flex-column-center">
    <div class="flex-center width90 height300 checkbox-div">
        <div>
            <ul>
                <li *ngFor="let role of context.roles">
                    <input class="roles-li" type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="role.id" name="role">{{ role.label }}
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="flex-column-center2 width35">
        <button class="btn-main10" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</div> 
</form>
```

My ts:

```
export class AddRolePopupComponent extends PopupAbstract<any> implements 
    OnInit {
    userRoles = [];


    constructor( private userService: UserService, private companyService: CompanyService, public dialog: DialogRef<any> ) {

        super( dialog, dialog.context );
    }

    ngOnInit() {        
        this.userService.getRolesForUser(this.context.id).subscribe(
            response => { this.handleSucess( response ); },
            error => { console.error( error ); },
        );
        }


    handleSucess(response) {
            this.userRoles = response;
    }

    submitRole(rolesForm){
        console.log(rolesForm.value);
    }   
}
```

What should I do to get my existing roles checked?

Comment: can you log `context.roles` and `userRoles` and tell me their content ?

Comment: Context.roles are array:
roles
:
Array(2)
0
:
{id: "cb53681a-608f-4ea5-a9a4-3826b30684b0", name: "ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN", label: "Company Administrator", type: "COMPANY"}
1
:
{id: "6235e566-b668-4780-ba9a-72e7f9e5a067", name: "ROLE_PROJECT_MANAGER", label: "Project Manager", type: "COMPANY"}

Comment: As for userRoles ...response in handleSucess is giving me array ... :
id
:
"cb53681a-608f-4ea5-a9a4-3826b30684b0"
label
:
"Company Administrator"
name
:
"ROLE_COMPANY_ADMIN"
type
:
"COMPANY"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what you have to do is to check if the `role.name` is one of the names of `userRoles` :

in your `.ts`file , map the `userRoles` to their `name`s :

```
userRolesNames = [];
handleSucess(response) {
            this.userRoles = response;
            this.userRolesNames = response.map(userRole => userRole.name);
}
```

in your HTML :

```
<input class="roles-li" type="checkbox" [checked]="userRolesNames.indexOf(role.name)>-1"  name="role">{{ role.label }}
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: It drops me an error ...think you can figure it out?
[ERROR ->][checked]="userRoles.map(userRole => userRole.name ).indexOf(role.name)>-1" [(ngModel)]="role.id" nam")

Comment: try to delete `[(ngModel)]="role.id"`

Comment: can show the whole error , and please verify your html code if it contains a syntaxic error , thanks :)

Comment: check my answer now :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [checked] directive in your input. [checked]="userRoles.indexOf(role.id)>-1"

Comment: Nothing is happening ...Every time when i open popup for list, all roles are checked... could be something else?